# Data not updated in TableView after searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller, uisearchbar

I have the following code to search a database for recipes then return that data to my View Controller:

```
var discoveredRecipe: RecipeDiscovered? = nil

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        var searchText = searchBar.searchTextField.text
        
        self.searchTask?.cancel()
        
        if searchText != "" {
            discoverModel.discoverRecipes(searchText: searchText ?? "") {
                self.searchTextActive = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }
```

I can confirm that the data is returned to my View Controller and assigned to `discoveredRecipe` in the above

I then have the following to display that returned data in my Table View:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        print("DiscoveredRecipe:\(discoveredRecipe)")
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MealPlanCell", for: indexPath) as! MealPlanCell
        
        // If searchText entered
        if searchTextActive == true {
            print("DiscoveredRecipe:\(discoveredRecipe)")
            cell.displayRecipeShort(recipeTitle: (discoveredRecipe?.hits![indexPath.row].recipe.label)!, recipeSourceUrl: (discoveredRecipe?.hits![indexPath.row].recipe.url)!, recipeImage: (discoveredRecipe?.hits![indexPath.row].recipe.image)!, indexPathRow: indexPath.row)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

It doesn't matter where I put `print("DiscoveredRecipe:\(discoveredRecipe)")` within `func tableView`, it keeps printing as `nil`. What am I missing to get the newly assigned `discoveredVariable` within the `func tableView` scope?

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to `discoveredRecipe`?

Comment: I have delegate-protocol that’s assigning it.

Comment: Show the code of that delegate and explain in detail how you verified that "data is returned to my View Controller and assigned to discoveredRecipe"

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your delegate method which is updating the discoveredRecipe is called or not.
if it is not called that's mean delegation is not setup properly.
That might be the problem discoveredRecipe value is nil.